# Post simple Strings to PHP script from iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

This seems like a question that has been asked several times before, however I cannot find any answer to it. I want to send a few pure text strings from my iOS app to my server. On the server side I have a PHP script ready and waiting, and my app uses a POST function, however i am unable to get this to run. Help please :)

PHP code on server (upload.php):

```
<?php
    $header = $_POST['header'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];

    echo "Header, description and city:" , '<br>', '<br>';

    echo "Header : " .$_REQUEST['header'], '<br>';
    echo "Desc : ".$_REQUEST['description'], '<br>';
    echo "City : ".$_REQUEST['city'], '<br>';
?>
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UITextField *header, *description, *city;
    IBOutlet UILabel *serverResponse;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController{
    NSMutableData *mutableData;

#define URL            @"http://myserver/upload.php"  // change this URL
#define NO_CONNECTION  @"No Connection"
#define NO_VALUES      @"Please enter parameter values"


}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(IBAction)sendDataUsingPost:(id)sender{

    [self sendDataToServer :@"POST"];

}

-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method{

    NSString *head  = header.text;
    NSString *desc = description.text;
    NSString *cty  = city.text;

    if(head.length > 0 && desc.length > 0 && cty.length > 0){

        NSURL *url = nil;
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;

        // Only Difference between POST and GET is only in the way they send parameters

        if([method isEqualToString:@"POST"]){

            NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"header=%@&description=%@&city=%@",head, desc, cty ];
            NSData *parameterData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            ;
            url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myserver/upload.php"];
            request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [request setHTTPBody:parameterData];

        }

        [request setHTTPMethod:method];
        [request addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if( connection )
        {

            mutableData = [NSMutableData new];

        }else{

            serverResponse.text = NO_CONNECTION;

        }

    }else{

        serverResponse.text = NO_VALUES;

    }

}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegates

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [mutableData setLength:0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [mutableData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    serverResponse.text = NO_CONNECTION;
    return;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"Response from Server : %@", responseStringWithEncoded);
    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[responseStringWithEncoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the problem, but why are you sending a `charset=utf-8` as MIME type and you are encoding your string in a ASCII data?

Comment: as far as i know (and this is not that very far) PHP is very picky with its utf-8 set up, that is why i put that snippet in there. however since i am far for an expert on this, i did that mostly on a hunch. do you think i should remove it/replace it? if so do you have any suggestions as to with what?

Comment: Honestly, I wrote a PHP web Service for me and I used only UTF-8 string encoding. Try to prepare a NSData with a `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: could you please give point at where in the code i should make updates?

Comment: Here: `NSData *parameterData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            ;`. Replace `NSASCIIStringEncoding` with `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: I updated the string, however i am still not seeing any updates to my PHP script. I did do some extra checks to see that the app actually communicates with the scrip and finds it ok - and it does! so im beginning to think that the problem is on the PHP side...

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` in echo. You are already assigning `$_POST` values to variables. So you can use `echo $header;` instead of `$_POST['header']`

Try

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $header = $_POST['header'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];

    echo "Header, description and city:" , '<br>', '<br>';

    echo "Header : " .$header.'<br>';
    echo "Desc : ".$description.'<br>';
    echo "City : ".$city.'<br>';
}
else
{
    echo 'There is no Post Request';
}
?>
```

You can `var_dump($_POST);` to see what you are receiving in post.

Comment: thank you hassan, but I am not sure that the values are even getting to the PHP script... what did you find of the iOS code? i think that is where the problem is ...

Comment: @Saucepan write `var_dump($_POST);` in top of you php file to see what you are receiving in post.

Comment: do you have any other ideas what may be the problem? I am actually starting to think that this PHP is the problem ... Can you see if it is receiving the parameters properly?

Comment: @Saucepan I'm PHP Developer. I can help you in PHP.

Comment: ok good, do you see any faults in the code? where do you think it when wrong?

Comment: @Saucepan yes, there were some errors in your PHP code. I have explain them in my answer. Please my provided code in your PHP File.